# Linking a shared library with unresolved symbols on linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, shared-libraries, dllexport

I have the following three projects:

- `Host`: An executable that exports a global variable (declared extern)
- `Plugin`: A runtime library that is loaded by `Host` and references the global variable
- `Tool`: An executable that links against the `Plugin` and uses some functionality of it. It doesn't reference the global variable in any way.

Now if I build this on windows everything is fine. The `Tool` will only link to the export library of the `Plugin` and will not try to resolve the global variable.

On linux I'm facing a problem. The `Tool` tries to link against the `Plugin` .so library (because there is no export library) and will find the reference to the global variable in `Host` which it can't resolve.

How to solve this problem?

---

Edit:

The following is a compilable example of the problem using CMake.

CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

SET(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Host)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Plugin)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(Tool)
```

Host/Host.h

```
#ifndef HOST_H
#define HOST_H

#ifdef _MSC_VER

#ifdef COMPILE_HOST
#define HOST_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define HOST_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#else
#define HOST_EXPORT
#endif


class HOST_EXPORT Host
{
public:
    int getAnswer();

};


extern HOST_EXPORT Host g_host;


#endif
```

Host/Host.cpp

```
#include "Host.h"
#include "../Plugin/Plugin.h"
#include <iostream>


Host g_host;


int Host::getAnswer()
{
    return 42;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << g_host.getAnswer() << std::endl;

    // load plugin and use it
}
```

Host/CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT(Host)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(Host Host.cpp Host.h)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DCOMPILE_HOST)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(Host PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS ON)
```

Plugin/Plugin.h

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_H
#define PLUGIN_H


class Plugin
{
public:
    Plugin();

};

#endif
```

Plugin/Plugin.cpp

```
#include "Plugin.h"
#include "../Host/Host.h"
#include <iostream>


Plugin::Plugin()
{
    std::cout << g_host.getAnswer() << std::endl;
}
```

Plugin/PluginFunc.h

```
#ifndef PLUGINFUNC_H
#define PLUGINFUNC_H

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define PLUGIN_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PLUGIN_EXPORT
#endif


namespace plug
{
    int PLUGIN_EXPORT getRandomNumber();
}

#endif
```

Plugin/PluginFunc.cpp

```
#include "PluginFunc.h"


int plug::getRandomNumber()
{
    return 4;
}
```

Plugin/CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT(Plugin)

ADD_LIBRARY(Plugin SHARED Plugin.cpp Plugin.h PluginFunc.cpp PluginFunc.h)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Plugin Host)
```

Tool/Tool.cpp

```
#include "../Plugin/PluginFunc.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::cout << plug::getRandomNumber() << std::endl;
}
```

Tool/CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT(Tool)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(Tool Tool.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Tool Plugin)
```

---

On Windows it builds and runs. Host.exe displays "42" and Tool.exe displays "4".

On Linux I get the following linking error:

```
usr@debian64:~/vbox/testlink/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target Host
[ 25%] Building CXX object Host/CMakeFiles/Host.dir/Host.o
Linking CXX executable Host
[ 25%] Built target Host
Scanning dependencies of target Plugin
[ 50%] Building CXX object Plugin/CMakeFiles/Plugin.dir/Plugin.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object Plugin/CMakeFiles/Plugin.dir/PluginFunc.o
Linking CXX shared library libPlugin.so
[ 75%] Built target Plugin
Scanning dependencies of target Tool
[100%] Building CXX object Tool/CMakeFiles/Tool.dir/Tool.o
Linking CXX executable Tool
../Plugin/libPlugin.so: undefined reference to `Host::getAnswer()'
../Plugin/libPlugin.so: undefined reference to `g_host'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Tool/Tool] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Tool/CMakeFiles/Tool.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you post some code/build scripts so we can see how your building on Win/Linux?

Comment: @txtechhelp I updated my question with a complete example.

Comment: Linking statically against an executable is highly unconventional. Any reason why you need to do this our you're just curious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two other approaches are:

- Define the global variable in Tool. It doesn't matter what the value is since it isn't used.
- Use linker commands to define the symbol with a made up value. With GCC and GNU ld it should be something like `gcc -Wl,--defsym=GlobalSymbol=0`

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible approaches:

1. Move the globals into a separate DLL that is referenced by both `Host` and `Plugin`.
2. Split `Plugin` into library functionality provided to `Tool` and plugin functionality provided to `Host` (implementing the plugin by invoking the library).

Either of these should work for you.

The link fails because you are linking the `Tool` program against the `Plugin` DLL, at which point the linker enforces that all symbols are resolvable. While lazy lookup would in principle avoid the problem at runtime, system policy could inhibit lazy lookup for security reasons, which would terminate your `Tool` immediately after invocation as there are undefined symbols in the process.

Comment: Thank you. This is the long term solution which I should aim towards, but I already knew that. I was looking for an answer that would solve my problem without too much work.